# LESS / CSS - Split unknown width container into four parts?

Tags: css, less

**Can this be done in LESS?**

I have a main container whose width I don't know. The width can vary, too, depending on the browser window width, etc.

Inside that container, I want to have 4 (or *n*) equally wide sub-containers (spans or divs).

Not knowing the actual width of the main container, is there any way to do some kind of calculation in LESS, that would simply refer to the main container's width as "the width" (for lack of better words), and then let me divide "the width" into 4?

---

PS: Feel free to correct or edit my question if I have used any confusing or incorrect nomenclature.

Comment: LESS will not help you.  You want flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overthinking it, you can do this with standard CSS by using percentages.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="quarter">Content 1</div>
    <div class="quarter">Content 2</div>
    <div class="quarter">Content 3</div>
    <div class="quarter">Content 4</div>
</div>
```

LESS/CSS

```
div.container {
    width: 100%;

    div.quarter {
        width: 25%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Instead of `float: left` you can try `display: inline-block` if you want to play a bit.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8fhcbh4g/)

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try. All I can think of is that 100% used to mean 100% of the available browser window width in IE. However, I appreciate your help with this. Thank you.